# VBA Lookup Loop

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office

I need to make a loop and I am having the hardest time. What I am trying to accomplish is to loop through all of the values in Column A of 'Assum'. The values start at A5. I then want it to lookup that same value on 'Sheet1' and check the Value of the 5th Column (E). Depending on the value within E (A, B, C) it does one of 3 tasks. The Task for C is to take the original value, and lookup that value within 'ECData', and take specific ranges and paste them onto a 4th sheet 'Work'.
What is actually happening: It is copying the cells from the incorrect row on 'ECData' rather than finding the specific line and pasting it's corresponding row.

I know the code is messy, I am trying to hobble together bits and pieces from other code that sort of accomplishes what I want.

Any thoughts?
MS Office 2013

```
Public y1 As Integer

Sub ECLoop()


Dim i As Single
Dim finalRow As Long



finalRow = Sheets("Assum").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 5 To finalRow
        If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 5) = "A" Then
            Sheets("Assum").Cells(i, 2) = "Test A"
        ElseIf Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 5) = "B" Then
            Sheets("Assum").Cells(i, 2) = "Test B"
        ElseIf Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 5) = "C" Then
            Set FoundCell = ActiveCell
                If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
                y1 = FoundCell.Row
                End If
            Set NationalPaste = Sheets("Work").Range("Z3")
            Set OverPaste = Sheets("Work").Range("Z24")
            Set UnderPaste = Sheets("Work").Range("Z45")
            Set IFPPaste = Sheets("Work").Range("Z66")
            Set SeniorsPaste = Sheets("Work").Range("Z87")
             Sheets("ECData").Select
                With Sheets("ECData")
                    Set National = Range(Cells(y1, 2), Cells(y1, 21))
                    Set Over = Range(Cells(y1, 22), Cells(y1, 41))
                    Set Under = Range(Cells(y1, 42), Cells(y1, 61))
                    Set IFP = Range(Cells(y1, 62), Cells(y1, 81))
                    Set Seniors = Range(Cells(y1, 82), Cells(y1, 101))
                End With


            Sheets("Work").Range("Z3:Z22").ClearContents
            National.Copy
            NationalPaste.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Transpose:=True

            Sheets("Work").Range("Z24:Z43").ClearContents
            Over.Copy
            OverPaste.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Transpose:=True

            Sheets("Work").Range("Z45:Z64").ClearContents
            Under.Copy
            UnderPaste.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Transpose:=True

            Sheets("Work").Range("Z66:Z85").ClearContents
            IFP.Copy
            IFPPaste.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Transpose:=True

            Sheets("Work").Range("Z87:Z106").ClearContents
            Seniors.Copy
            SeniorsPaste.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Transpose:=True
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: You set `FoundCell = ActiveCell` by doing this You set it to the same cell every time (you don't seem to move it programatically). Also you should remove all of your static values from the loop e.g. `Set NationalPaste = Sheets("Work").Range("Z3")` never changes it's value so set it once instead of setting it every loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not completely answer your question but it's far too long for a comment. If you will answer my questions (see code comments) I'll update it to fix what I think is your issue; however, you can probably do this yourself with the info below). I've also tidied up your code a bit

```
' Use Option Explicit to ensure all variables are declared - will save you a lot of debugging time
Option Explicit
Sub ECLoop()
    ' Make sure you declare all your variables
    ' Why is y1 public? Is it used elsewhere? Try to keep it local
    Dim i As Long, finalRow As Long, y1 As Long
    Dim NationalPaste As Range, OverPaste As Range, UnderPaste As Range, IFPPaste As Range, SeniorsPaste As Range
    Dim FoundCell As Range, National As Range, Over As Range, Under As Range, IFP As Range, Seniors As Range

    finalRow = Sheets("Assum").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    With Sheets("Work")
        Set NationalPaste = .Range("Z3")
        Set OverPaste = .Range("Z24")
        Set UnderPaste = .Range("Z45")
        Set IFPPaste = .Range("Z66")
        Set SeniorsPaste = .Range("Z87")
    End With

    For i = 5 To finalRow
        If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 5) = "A" Then
            Sheets("Assum").Cells(i, 2) = "Test A"
        ElseIf Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 5) = "B" Then
            Sheets("Assum").Cells(i, 2) = "Test B"
        ElseIf Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 5) = "C" Then
            ' I think this is causing your error as it will always be the same
            ' Set this to what it should be e.g. Set FoundCell = Sheets("Assum").Cells(i,1)
            Set FoundCell = ActiveCell
            ' This If is fairly pointless as it will always be set. You also don't seem to resuse FoundCell
            ' So why not just set y1 straight away
            If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
                y1 = FoundCell.Row
            End If

            With Sheets("ECData")
                Set National = .Range(.Cells(y1, 2), .Cells(y1, 21))
                Set Over = .Range(.Cells(y1, 22), .Cells(y1, 41))
                Set Under = .Range(.Cells(y1, 42), .Cells(y1, 61))
                Set IFP = .Range(.Cells(y1, 62), .Cells(y1, 81))
                Set Seniors = .Range(.Cells(y1, 82), .Cells(y1, 101))
            End With

            With Sheets("Work")
                .Range("Z3:Z22").ClearContents
                National.Copy
                NationalPaste.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Transpose:=True

                .Range("Z24:Z43").ClearContents
                Over.Copy
                OverPaste.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Transpose:=True

                .Range("Z45:Z64").ClearContents
                Under.Copy
                UnderPaste.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Transpose:=True

                .Range("Z66:Z85").ClearContents
                IFP.Copy
                IFPPaste.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Transpose:=True

                .Range("Z87:Z106").ClearContents
                Seniors.Copy
                SeniorsPaste.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Transpose:=True
            End With
        Else
            ' Do you really want it to quit if the the cell doesn't equal your test conditions
            ' What about the rest of the cells?
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much Tom.  With your framework I was able to adjust mine accordingly and got it to work!

Comment: Glad you've got it sorted